# How can I return a particular value from a column?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following sheets:

Main Workbook

[image: Main Workbook]

Other sheet

[image: Other Sheet]

In the Main workbook, In cell F2, I want to return the value corresponding to the ISO and the YEAR in the other sheet. Like for example, in cell F2 i want to return the value = 5.22 from the other sheet (cell C2) and in cell F13 i want to return the value = 7.08 (cell C18 from other sheet).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUMIFS:

```
=SUMIFS(OtherSheet!C:C,OtherSheet!A:A,A2,OtherSheet!B:B,C2)
```

Comment: *Lots* better than what I was going to suggest - an Index/Match on concatenated columns.

Comment: @Bandersnatch see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another  I kind of go through all the options.

Comment: That's a great reference.  @Jeeped sounds like an interesting fellow.